# C++/Win32 The basics of FTP security and using SSL

Tags: c++, winapi, ftp

My application downloads files from an FTP server.

Using a packet sniffer I can see the user name and password easily, I would like to have this avoided.

I can't make an FTP account with limited privileges ATM.

How do I know if the server supports SSL? (Apache 2.x.x)

Any other way to hide user : pass of FTP account?

Comment: FTP isn't particularly good or modern. If possible, I would recommend using HTTPS or SSH instead. Good luck anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see if a FTP server supports FTPS in explicit mode ([RFC 2228](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2228), [RFC 4217](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4217)), then send an `AUTH TLS`. If it replies with a `5xx` error code, then it doesn't; if it replies with a `234`, then it does and your client should react appropriately (which, for a RFC 4217 compliant server, means doing a standard TLS handshake).

Unfortunately the WinInet API doesn't let you do this, so you might want to look at [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), which supports FTPS out of the box.

Comment: how exactly do I send that message? open source code available?

Comment: FTP is a "plaintext" protocol, so you literally send that string `AUTH TLS` - but then you need to be able to perform a TLS handshake (which is also standardized and doable with e.g. the OpenSSL library).

Comment: I use high level windows functions for my FTP needs, and I'm not very much familiar with using sockets.

Comment: @user1581390 It doesn't look like WinInet supports FTPS at all; try libcurl instead (see revised response).

Comment: Yup sounds like a nice library for most applications, I am however not looking forward to the bloating of my .exe as a result of including it. I'll try compiling with it and then extracting just the code I need.