# FTP NLST results in '425: Can't open data connection for transfer' only on some client machines

Tags: c++, windows, ssl, ftp, wininet

I'm currently running a FileZilla FTP server on a network. My issue is that on seemingly random machines, when the user navigates to a directory (which they are able to do) and attempts to ls (i.e. data transfer) their end hangs waiting for a response, while the server reports this `425: Can't open data connection for transfer` mentioned above. This result varies depending on the client machine used, where some (either local or remote) are able to proceed and others stuck here. I understand that this is because simple FTP commands like `CWD`ing operate on the 20/21 ports, whereas FTP data transfer operate on some other port number, which in turn may be blocked by a firewall somewhere along the chain. My question is, how do I account for these varying ports (if this truly is the issue), as as best I know they could be anything above 1024?

My end goal with this project is to implement a very simple FTP solution, ideally using WinINet, however, so far I've run into the same problem:

```
BOOL CWebFileFinder::FindFile(const CString& URL)
{
    CString ServerName;
    CString strObject;
    INTERNET_PORT nPort;
    DWORD dwServiceType = AFX_INET_SERVICE_FTP;
    if (AfxParseURL(URL, dwServiceType, ServerName, strObject, nPort))
    {
        m_Connection = m_Session.GetFtpConnection(ServerName, m_Username, m_Password, nPort/*, true*/);  // results in findfile still failing
        if (m_Connection)
        {
            m_Connection->SetCurrentDirectory("sms");  // CDs into this dir
            m_Finder = new CFtpFileFind(m_Connection);
            if (m_Finder)
            {
                More = m_Finder->FindFile(_T("*.*"));  // hangs here
            }
        }
    }
    catch (CException* pEx)
    {
        CString str;
        LPTSTR error = str.GetBuffer(255);
        pEx->GetErrorMessage(error, 255);
        pEx->Delete();
        str.ReleaseBuffer();
    }
    return More;
}
```

As far as I can see, either I need to call to open this data port prior to the `LIST`, or find the firewalls blocking these ports and create a rule to prevent that ([What ports does Wininet listen on for Active FTP data connection?](https://serverfault.com/a/278246)). Of course I could also be just completely off-base – Any insights at all would be **greatly** appreciated!

Comment: Quite on the contrary, use the passive mode (`PASV`, not `PORT`). The active mode will hardly work. See my [article on FTP modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes) to understand why.  – In general, this is not a programming issue. If you want to use FTP, the machine setup must allow the FTP network connectivity. No code will solve that.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl thanks for the link, I'll have a look. When I set the ftp connection to passive (uncommenting that final arg), the user immediately disconnects after:
`> 257 "/" is current directory.
> CWD sms
> 250 CWD successful. "/sms" is current directory.
> TYPE A
> 200 Type set to A
> PASV
> 227 Entering Passive Mode(<server ip address>, 198, 9)
> disconnected.`
I know windows command line uses an implementation of ftp that doesn't support passive, would it be fair to assume that WinINet uses the same implementation? or do you have an alternative suggestion?

Comment: No WinINet  supports the passive mode. + Can you retrieve the directory listing using any (GUI) FTP client that runs on the same machine?

Comment: Yeah, FileZilla client lists the contents of directories with no problem. I take it that means there's a fault in my code then?

Comment: Please post a verbose log file of FileZilla.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/JCUyHs2E

Comment: That's for encrypted (TLS/SSL) FTP. Does FileZilla work even if you turn off the encryption? – Also is the `Server IP address` in `227 Entering Passive Mode (<Server IP address>,209,3)` really the IP address you connect to? (the same one as in the `Connecting to <Server IP address>:21`...)

Comment: I don't really see how the encryption factors into all this? No, it doesn't work if it's turned off. And no, of course it isn't, I imagine we'd have bigger problems if it were 

Comment: Well your code does not do any encryption. So if FileZilla does not work without encryption, it's only natural that your code does not work either. – I do not understand your other response. Or you did not understand my question. Do you mean that the IP address in the `227` line is **different** than the one in the `Connecting to` line?  (note that I understand that you have replaced the actual IP address with a placeholder text)

Comment: Oh I see, my mistake! Yes, that's a good point, I'll look into that.
And yes those two IP addresses were the same, however, whether they both relate to the server or not I can't say for sure, as both machines were both on the same network, so it's possible that one of those IP addresses relates to the client machine.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl on further review, it seems TLS encryption (that which is default in FileZilla client) is the default option in WinINet also, so I suspect this isn't the real issue:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wndp/2006/04/12/tls-enabled-by-default-in-ie-7-0-and-wininet/

Comment: Imo, it applies only to HTTP(S) (when you use `https://` URL), but not to FTP (there's no way to tell WinInet to use TLS with FTP). See for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/12019819/850848 – After all, you can verify that in your server log.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, apologies for the late reply, but this seemed to be the root of the problem. Thank you for all your help. Feel free to surmise this as the answer to the problem and ill mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your FTP server seems to require an encrypted connection (TLS/SSL).

WinInet does not support encrypted FTP.
See [C++/Win32 The basics of FTP security and using SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12019819/850848).